# OFFSET N FETCH FIRST M ROWS with JDBC and PostgreSQL not working

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to make a query using JDBC and PostgreSQL, but I'm facing a weird situation that I can't find in any documentation.

The following query works if I execute it through pgAdmin and H2 (which I'm using for unit tests for my application), but I'm getting a syntax error if I execute it through JDBC:

`Queries.SELECT_SQL`

```
SELECT columns 
  FROM Table 
  LEFT JOIN TableToJoin1 
  LEFT JOIN TableToJoin2 
  LEFT JOIN TableToJoin3 
  JOIN TableToJoin4
```

---

`Queries.ENDING_PAGING_STATEMENT_SQL`

```
OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH FIRST ? ROWS ONLY
```

---

The `SELECT` query is correct and works fine using any means, the problem is when I get both queries together, i.e., the `SELECT` statement along with `OFFSET` and `FETCH FIRST`.

This is how I'm executing the query through `JDBC`:

```
// Receive offset and limit as argument.
try (final PreparedStatement selectStatement = connection
        .prepareStatement(Queries.SELECT_SQL + Queries.ENDING_PAGING_STATEMENT_SQL)) {

  selectStatement.setInt(Queries.PAGING_ENDING_STATEMENT_OFFSET_ARGUMENT_POSITION, offset);
  selectStatement.setInt(Queries.PAGING_ENDING_STATEMENT_LIMIT_ARGUMENT_POSITION, limit);

  final ResultSet resultSet = bookSelectStatement.executeQuery();
  ...
}
```

Here is the message of the exception that's being thrown:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
```

---

If I call `selectStatement.toString()` for debugging, I receive the query exactly as I expect.

If I change `OFFSET N ROWS FETCH FIRST M ROWS ONLY` by `OFFSET N LIMIT M` it will work through JDBC without any problem.
The simplest solution would make that simple change above, but part of my task is to make a query using this `FETCH FIRST M ROWS ONLY` statement.

So, can you guys help me to see if I'm doing it wrong, or if there's no way of using `FETCH FIRST` on JDBC for PostgreSQL at all? With some examples or some references to any documentation that would help.

I noticed that `FETCH FIRST` doesn't exist on [PostgreSQL Documentation: Queries - Offset and Limit](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-limit.html), but since it works through pgAdmin I don't know why I should have any problem using JDBC.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `fetch first` is document in the chapter about the [`select` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) - looks like a documentation bug

Comment: Also you can't provide the limit/offset as a assignable parameter in `PreparedStatement`. Actually this might no longer be true and depend on the driver.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name, it was hidden in the index, but it looks that I'm not doing anything wrong to the query.

Comment: @Kayaman, but if I change `OFFSET N ROWS FETCH FIRST M ROWS ONLY` for `OFFSET N LIMIT M` it would work correctly, without changing anything on the `PreparedStatement`, why should it be different?

Comment: It seems that `PreparedStatement` does allow parameterizing limit/offset, but I could've sworn I've had trouble with that before. I might be thinking of some obfuscation layer that doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem. As of version 10, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT) says:

> In this syntax, to write anything except a simple integer constant for start or count, you must write parentheses around it

Which is ridiculous, of course. Bind variables should be allowed without parentheses - most databases allow them and the `OFFSET ? LIMIT ?` syntax is also accepted by PostgreSQL, but it looks as though they aren't in PostgreSQL's interpretation of the standard SQL syntax. So you'll have to write:

```
OFFSET (?) ROWS FETCH FIRST (?) ROWS ONLY
```

[I would consider this a bug, which I've reported here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/152647780335.27204.16895288237122418685%40wrigleys.postgresql.org)

Comment: Oops, I'm using it, I just forgot to write it on the question, thank you.
But it gives me the same error with or without that keyword.

Comment: Whaaaaat? Okay.. That was really helpful, I didn't have any notes about it on the lesson I had, so this is something new, unexpected. Thank you, it works properly now!

Comment: _"it looks as though they aren't in the standard SQL syntax"_ The SQL standard allows literals or parameters (but not columns, etc), and it doesn't allow expressions. Technically parentheses aren't even allowed by the standard. (SQL:2016-2 7.17)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I've reverted your change and added a clear version indicator. I believe this to be a bug that should be fixed, so in the future, the manual might say something different

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Yeah, fixed my wording. I didn't mean it this way

Comment: I was just rechecking the spec, and a literal reading suggests a positional parameter may actually not be allowed. It seems like they accidentally used `<SQL parameter reference>` instead of `<dynamic parameter specification>` (or forgot to include it: I'm not sure if `<SQL parameter reference>` would make sense for a `<simple value specification>`). So technically, PostgreSQL may actually be correct ;)